# Using variables in gdbinit script

Tags: gdb

I'd like to use variables inside .gdbinit script to later expand it in `add-symbole-file`. However for some reason the variable is not expanded.

```
set $project_root = C:/Projects/Gitlab/ASW

...

add-symbol-file $project_root/fm_bc/FM_Lib.out
```

I tried to use `$project_root` as `$(project_root)` and `${project_root}`.

I'm using `arm-none-eabi-gdb` (*GNU gdb (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 7.10.1.20160923-cvs*) without Python support and recompilation on Windows is not possible.